# Spring 4 upgrade broke error page filter chain

Tags: spring-mvc

Scenario:
We have an interceptor that looks for bogus attributes in URLs and throws a `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` if it finds one.  We then display a custom 404 page.

All pages go through the same filter chain to set up the local request state, log some information, and then display the requested page.  In Spring 4, it stopped going through the filter chain for the 404 page in this case.  It still goes through it if you go to a completely bogus page, and the 404 works, but when we throw the `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException`, the filters don't happen.

Spring 3:
 1. Runs the filter chain for the main request
 2. We throw `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException`
 3. Filter chain finishes
 4. New filter chain starts
 5. We log the error page metrics
 6. We display a nice 404 page to the customer

Spring 4:
 1. Runs the filter chain for the main request
 2. We throw `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException`
 3. Filter chain finishes
 4. We try to log the error page metrics, but NPE since a second filter chain never started
 5. We display a terrible blank page to the customer

Filter code in web.xml:

```
    <!-- The filter that captures the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse--> 
     <filter>
      <filter-name>ServletObjectFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
          <param-value>xxxxxxx.servletObjectFilter</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>ServletObjectFilter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

...

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/404</location>
    </error-page>
```

Filter code:

```
public void doFilterInternal( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain )
                throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        getServletContainer().setServletObjects( request, response );
        chain.doFilter( request, response );
    } finally {
        getServletContainer().removeAll();
    }
```

ServletContainer:

```
static final ThreadLocal< HttpServletRequest > REQUESTS = new ThreadLocal< HttpServletRequest >();
static final ThreadLocal< HttpServletResponse > RESPONSES = new ThreadLocal< HttpServletResponse >();

public void setServletObjects( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) {
    REQUESTS.set( request );
    RESPONSES.set( response );
}

public void removeAll() {
    REQUESTS.remove();
    RESPONSES.remove();
}
```

Code that then fails:

```
  public class RequestResponseAwareBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization( Object bean, String beanName ) {
       ...
       if ( bean instanceof RequestAware ) {
            HttpServletRequest request = getServletContainer().getRequest();
            if ( request == null ) {
                throw new IllegalStateException( "The request object is NULL" );
            }

            RequestAware requestAware = (RequestAware) bean;
            requestAware.setRequest( request );
        }
      }
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you using filters or interceptors? There is only a single filter chain so you aren't starting a new one (unless you hack around something yourself?). Post some code as you now only have a part of the web.xml.

Comment: We're using both filters and interceptors.  We use a filter to inject state that we need into Spring, and then we use that state in our interceptors.  Maybe we were hacking around something ourselves that stopped working with Spring 4.  The web.xml is over 300 lines long, unfortunately.

Comment: Hopefully I've added more code that's useful.  I added the filter that runs twice on Spring 3, and only once on Spring 4, and the BeanPostProcessor that fails initializing our Interceptors on Spring 4 since it assumes the Filter has run.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" the problem by splitting up my error page @Controller into two, one where they're the targets of internal redirects and don't get the filter chain, and one where they are directly loaded, and do get the filter chain.  I then added the redirect @Controller to the interceptor blacklist, so it doesn't require any logic or data from the filters.  It solved this specific problem, but I'm worried that something else in my codebase also relies on this behavior.